# Why no race conditions in std:cout in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, race-condition

I wanted to show a friend a simple race condition example based on std:cout as a shared resource, as described in [this article](https://www.acodersjourney.com/top-20-cplusplus-multithreading-mistakes/).

So, I entered the following code in a brand new Visual Studio 2019 console application:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void CallHome(string message)
{
    cout << "Thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " says " << message << endl;
}

int main()
{
    thread t1(CallHome, "Hello from Jupiter");
    thread t2(CallHome, "Hello from Pluto");
    thread t3(CallHome, "Hello from Moon");
    CallHome("Hello from Main/Earth");
    thread t4(CallHome, "Hello from Uranus");
    thread t5(CallHome, "Hello from Neptune");
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
    t5.join();
    return 0;
}
```

According to the article and its screenshot for Visual Studio 2015, I expected the output text to get messed up with interleaved fragments from different threads.

However, I consistently got the following output on every run of my program:

```
Thread 1472 says Hello from Main/Earth
Thread 15112 says Hello from Jupiter
Thread 9248 says Hello from Neptune
Thread 17876 says Hello from Pluto
Thread 18452 says Hello from Uranus
Thread 18088 says Hello from Moon
```

What's going on there? What has changed in C++ runtime lately? Is it something related to threading or std:cout that now makes it free from race conditions?

Comment: Try to output something in a longer loop inside the tread and you will see them interfering. Also I see the order of outputs is not the same as order of inputs, it is because of threading. You can be sure is not single threaded.

Comment: Add `std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);` in the tail of ur void to make it longer. I used vs and the same code with the addition and then have seen the race condition(interleaving outputs).

Comment: https://rextester.com/live/DJAQ2285

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but this question asks about a **generic** meaning of race condition. The C++ standard has a narrower definition of race condition, and the standard streams are required to be implemented in a way that prevents race conditions in that narrower sense. So be careful here; the interleaving that this code seeks to demonstrate is, in some usages, a race condition, but in the formal sense that the C++ standard defines, it is not a race condition.

Comment: @PeteBecker  Yep, in this case my demo was meant more for a logical, high level race condition when accessing a shared resource (std:out) and not about technical thread safety (when you risk getting memory access violations and crashes if using non-thread-safe code and third-party resources). So, I guess, std:out as such is thread safe (no crashes etc.), but still it can lead to logical race conditions, depending on programmer's expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed `void CallHome(string message)` to print messages 100 times per thread,

```
void CallHome(string message)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        cout << "Thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " says " << message << endl;
}
```

and I got the following messages.

```
Thread 10588 says Hello from Uranus
Thread 10588 says Hello from Uranus
Thread 10588 says Thread 8116 says Hello from Neptune
Hello from Uranus
Thread 10588 says Hello from Uranus
```

A race condition can be found where many threads are trying to acquire a shared resources. 5 times of try is too few to inspect it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I guess since that article CPUs have gotten noticeably more powerful, so they execute the threads faster and there is not enough time for a race condition to occur.

Comment: @JustAMartin Glad to hear that it helps. Race conditions are very difficult to detect. They're hardly found but very critical.